# Volume of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I'm reviewing for a final exam and found a great question that I would like some assistance with!

Write two integrals representing the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region ecnlsoed by the 
$$y-axis$$ $$y=\sqrt{x}$$ $$y=2-x^3$$ about the line $$y=2$$ One integral should be with respect to x while the other should be with respect to y.

So when I did this problem I was rotating the solid to the right using the shell method, but I think I was doing the problem totally wrong. It should be rotating upwards and I shouldn't need to use the shell method, but I'm not sure how to do it without the shell method. Any explanations would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a careful diagram, and identify visually the region we are rotating. The analyses below won't make much sense without the picture.

Note that the two curves $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=2-x^3$ meet at $x=1$. (There is no pleasant "algebraic" way to solve the equation $\sqrt{x}=2-x^3$, but we can see by inspection that $x=1$ works. And it is clear that there is only one real solution, since $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing and $2-x^3$ is decreasing.)

**Slicing:** We take cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis. We get a "washer" (a disk with a hole in it), The outer radius of the washer is $2-\sqrt{x}$, and the inner radius is $2-(2-x^3)$, which is $x^3$. Thus the area of cross-section is $\pi\left((2-\sqrt{x})^2-(x^3)^2\right)$. It follows that the volume is 
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \pi\left((2-\sqrt{x})^2-(x^3)^2\right)\,dx.$$

**Shells:** Take a thin slice at height $y$, going from $y$ to $y+dy$, and rotate it about the line $y=2$. We get a cylindrical shell. The radius of the shell is always $2-y$. But the height of the cylinder varies, depending on whether $0\le y\le 1$ or $1\le y\le 2$.

If $0\le y\le 1$, the height of the shell is $x$, which is $y^2$. Integrating from $y=0$ to $y=1$, we get a contribution of 
$$\int_{y=0}^1 2\pi(2-y)y^2\,dy\tag{1}$$
to the volume.
The analysis is much the same from $y=1$ to $y=2$, but here $x=(2-y)^{1/3}$. That gives a contribution of 
$$\int_{y=1}^2 2\pi(2-y)(2-y)^{1/3}\,dy\tag{2}$$
to the volume. finally, add integrals (1) and (2).

**Remark:** In your picture, you will have drawn the horizontal line $y=2$. The region of interest is below the line, so yes, we are rotating upwards.

Doing it by Shells is sort of necessary. Slicing is easier, but the question asked for **two** methods.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I fully understand now!

Comment: You are welcome. Usually everything becomes clear once we have a clear view of the geometry.